how to add accessibility to a X/Y text?
I have a table where one of the columns has info about deployments: X/Y. as in 5 successful deployments out of 15 deployments (X and Y are numbers, here X=5 and Y=15)
how can I make this element more accessible?
so my table looks like this:
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
    <tr>
      <th>Deployment status</th>
    </tr>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
    <tr><td>5/15</td></tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>

I'm asking that for testing, but I also want to make the table more accessible
I'm looking for an answer with a suggested HTML tag or aria attributes

There’s some details missing. Best would be if you added some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example What are X and Y? Are they symbols or actual text? Are they simply numbers? What are the table headings for the respective columns? Are they marked up correctly with <th>?

added some details. X and Y are numbers

What do you mean by more accessible? How does that reflect into your desired behavior?

how can I make 5/15 readable for a screen reader?

That's already text. It should be readable for a screen reader. What do you want it to say, "5 out of 15" or something?

see my answer - "5 succesful deployments out 15 total deployments"

my solution was to wrap each value with a span with aria-label:
for X=5 and Y=15
  <span aria-label="5 Successful deployments">5</span>
  /
  <span aria-label="15 Total deployments">15</span>


If X and Y are abbreviations to represent the states, this fails Label in Name, which asks for the visible text to be included in the accessible name. You would at least need to prefix those.

This is a possible solution, but very verbose. It’s circumventing the table, who’s purpose is to centralise labels by providing column headings. It isn’t clarifying things for users without screen readers either. Using title might be better for that.

which title? aren't title less accessible than aria-labels?
